# Задать опции для файлов без точки с помощью autocmd

Tags: vim

Как задать опции форматирования для файлов, в названиях которых
**не** содержится точка?  Например, в исполняемых
*Shell*-скриптах.  Данный вариант не работает:

```vim
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile [^.]+ setlocal noexpandtab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `autocmd` особенный язык шаблонов с кучей подвохов.  Вот
рабочий вариант вашего кода:

```vim
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile [^.]\\\{1,\} setlocal noexpandtab
```

Три обратных знака дроби обязательны.
[Документация](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-patterns).